# Return string value of random values from multidimensional array using recursion function

Tags: php

I'm stuck with the following problem. I need to generate a sentence based on word and phrase values from JSON string. Some parts of sentence may be random selection based on values, provided in array.

Example JSON:

```
$json = '{"s1":    [
                    "I like fruit ",
                    [
                        "banana",
                        "plums",
                        "strawberry"
                    ],
                    "and vegetable "
                    [
                        "tomato",
                        "carrot",
                        "potato"
                    ]
                    ]
}';
```

Final string may be "I like fruit banana and vegetable carrot". I'll have several similar JSONs to combine a paragraph.

My code:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_recursive($data, $data);

function print_recursive($arr, $parent_arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            if(check_strings_in_array($val)){
                $str .= $val[rand(0, count($val) - 1)].' ';
            }
            print_recursive($val, $val);
        } else {
            if(count($parent_arr)>0){
                if(!check_strings_in_array($parent_arr)){
                    $str .=  $val . " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo $str;
    //// return $str - need to return a value, not echo
};

function check_strings_in_array($arr)
{
    return array_sum(array_map('is_string', $arr)) == count($arr);
}
```

I can't figure out how to assign a print_recursive() result to a variable for later use. If I write:

$final = print_recursive($data, $data);

It shows empty value. I tried "return print_recursive($val, $val)" or "return $val", but it doesn't give desired result.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Change `echo $str;` to `return $str` then use `$final = print_recursive($data, $data);`. If you don't `return` it isn't sent back. `echo` throws the response to the output buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to a store (variable), which receives the result of your recursive function.

### Following logic:

```
<?php
$store = ''; // the result store
print_recursive($data, $data, $store);

var_dump($store); // string(47) "I like fruit strawberry and vegetable carrot "

function print_recursive($arr, $parent_arr, &$str) { // added a store reference: &$str
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            if(check_strings_in_array($val)){
                $str .= $val[rand(0, count($val) - 1)].' ';
            }
            print_recursive($val, $val, $str); // added $str
        } else {
            if(count($parent_arr)>0){
                if(!check_strings_in_array($parent_arr)){
                    $str .=  $val . " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/8ZSkC)

EDIT:

### How to return the result

If you'd also like the result `$str` returned from the recursive function, just use: `return $str` before the closing function brace `}`.

This working [demo](https://3v4l.org/ZRHfW) shows how you can get the returned `$str` from your recursive function - we store it in `$result`.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks a lot! But is there a way to make the function return result as a variable? It would make the code more usable.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Don't mention it. Glad I could help!